# Shapes disappearing

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

Alright, I figured out everything that I got but now I am really stuck. Every time you choose a different shape the previously selected one disappears. How do I make it so they don't disappear and stay on the screen until you exit?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ShapeStamper extends JFrame{
    Random rand = new Random();
    public int x;
    public int y;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2;
    private JButton button1, button2, button3, button4;
    private int option = 0;

public ShapeStamper(){
    super("Shape Stamper!");
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    button1 = new JButton("Circle");
    button2 = new JButton("Square");
    button3 = new JButton("Rectangle");
    button4 = new JButton("Oval");

    button1.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            option = 1;
                }
            }
    );
     button2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            option = 2;
                }
            }
    );
     button3.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            option = 3;
                }
            }
    );
     button4.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            option = 4;
                }
            }
    );
  panel2 = new JPanel();
  panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  MouseHandler mouse = new MouseHandler();
  setVisible(true);
  addMouseListener(mouse);
  addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
  add(panel2);
  panel1.add(button1);
  panel1.add(button2);
  panel1.add(button3);
  panel1.add(button4);

  add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  setSize(500,500);
  setVisible(true);
          }
private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener{
        @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        repaint();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if(option == 0){
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
        g.drawString("Shape Stamper!", 150, 220);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
        g.drawString("Programmed by: Chris", 150, 230);
    }
    if(option == 1){
        Color randColor1 = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        g2d.setPaint(randColor1);
        g2d.drawOval(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }
    if(option == 2){
        Color randColor2 = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        g2d.setPaint(randColor2);
        g2d.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
            }
    if(option == 3){
        Color randColor3 = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        g2d.setPaint(randColor3);
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(75,50,150,100));
            }
    if(option == 4){
        Color randColor4 = new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
        g2d.setPaint(randColor4);
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 25, 100, 50));
            }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShapeStamper application = new ShapeStamper();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    }
```

Comment: `paintComponent` is not a method of `JFrame`...

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you. I got that part out of the way :)

Comment: This should be tagged swing, not netbeans. The code's going to do the same thing regardless of what IDE you use, and it's a Swing question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be overriding `paint` of a top level container and then trying to painting over the top of the components you have already added.

The basic problem you will encounter is, the paint system is clever enough that it may not ever call `paint` of the frame, but simply update the child components directly instead.

Instead, create yourself a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting there.  Then add this component to your frame.

You will also find the the paint updates are cleaner and won't flicker when updated.

You should also make sure you are calling `repaint` on this custom component when ever you change one it's options to ensure that changes are painted back to the component

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Also, just to be clear, you should not be calling `super.paintComponents` from `paint` (or in fact anywhere except for when you override `paintComponents`...which there really should be a need to do...)

Comment: Would I need to create another class for it or can I just put it in the one I have the coding in? Also, will it help make the shapes not disappear?

Comment: 1- Basically, I would replace `panel2` with a custom/extended component which contained the content from your current `paint` method (but calling the correct super method). 2- No, it won't stop the shapes from disappearing, as this is how you have coded it

Comment: Oh. Well do you know how I could make them not disappear?

Comment: Painting is a destructive process.  Each time `paintComponent` is called, you will need to re-paint EVERYTHING you want painted.  Basically, instead of having a single `int` flag, you may consider using a `List` and possible using the `Shape` API.  This way you can add and remove `Shape`s from the `List` and when `paintComponent` is called, you would simply iterate the `List` and paint what ever is in it...